# Find Implementation Files

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Is there any way to access Cocoa implementation(.m files not .h files) files in Xcode. I am using Xcode 6.4. I would like to explore implementation methods of classes
For Eg NSView, NSTableView etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apple doesn't expose implementation files for it's proprietary classes. Those are private.

Answer (score 1):

Although Apple doesn't expose the implementation files, you can examine class-dumped runtime headers to gain an understanding of how Apple may have implemented a feature.

[GitHub is one source for such repositories](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=runtime%20headers&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) although you'll find the runtime headers documented on many other sites.

While educational, you don't want to rely on any private methods or properties, as those internals can change even if the public API has not.

Comment: Thanks for the link provided :-)